# ros2 emit change state event to lifecyle node which are started individually in different processes not robust

Tags: ros-humble, ros2-launch, launch

i'am working on ros2 lifecycle node and launch system, I have follow issue:
I want to run multiple lifecycle nodes through LaunchService in different process due to some reason. However I noticed that lifecycle node doesn't make the expected state chage mostly(sometimes it works.it's flaky).
Here is my code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
from typing import List

from launch.actions import EmitEvent, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
import launch.events
from launch.launch_description import LaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_entity import LaunchDescriptionEntity
from launch.launch_service import LaunchService
import launch_ros
from launch_ros.actions import LifecycleNode
from launch_ros.events.lifecycle import ChangeState
import lifecycle_msgs.msg
import rclpy


class MyLauncher():
    def generate_launch_description(self):
        launch_elements: List[List[LaunchDescriptionEntity]] = [[]]
        for ns in ['room1', 'room2']:
            lc_node = LifecycleNode(
                package='lifecycle_py',
                executable='lifecycle_talker',
                name='talker',
                namespace=ns,
                output='screen',
            )
            # emit configure
            emit_configure = RegisterEventHandler(
                OnProcessStart(
                    target_action=lc_node,
                    on_start=[
                        EmitEvent(event=ChangeState(
                            lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.matches_action(lc_node),
                            transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_CONFIGURE,
                        ))
                    ]))

            #  send activate when on_configure finished
            emit_active = RegisterEventHandler(
                launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
                    target_lifecycle_node=lc_node,
                    goal_state='inactive',
                    entities=[
                        EmitEvent(event=ChangeState(
                            lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.matches_action(lc_node),
                            transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_ACTIVATE,
                        )),
                    ],
                ))

            launch_elements.append([lc_node,
                                    emit_configure,
                                    emit_active,
                                    ])

        return launch_elements

    def launch_task(self, launch_description):
        ls = LaunchService()
        ls.include_launch_description(LaunchDescription(launch_description))
        ls.run()

    def launch(self):
        procs: List[Process] = []
        for launch_description in self.generate_launch_description():
            proc = Process(target=self.launch_task, args=(launch_description,))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    rclpy.create_node('test')
    launcher = MyLauncher()
    launcher.launch()
    print('end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

i use talker immplemeted in this [demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/humble/lifecycle_py) package in my code.

### Expected behavior

both /room1/talker and /room2/talker trans to active state and keep publishing message.

### Actual behavior

sometimes both on the two lifecycle nodes, sometimes one of them, sometimes none of them trans to active sate.

### Additional information

After I started this python program, i still can change node state from unconfigured to active state by

```
ros2 lifecycle set /room1/lifecycle_talker configure
```

from a terminal.

Also, I notice that if the line

```
rclpy.create_node('test')
```

is comment out, everything works perfect as my expected.

Do I miss something?